# Should I redo PVC that needs to be forced into position?

Tags: plumbing, adhesive, pvc, joints

I'm in the middle of a bathroom remodel, and the plumber I hired redid the drain for the vanity based on a recommendation from the inspector to get it under the joist level (which I appreciated, because I spent a lot of time leveling the floor to minimize the lip going into the bathroom).

The redo connects with the tub drain at a 3/4" lower point to accomplish getting the pipe below the joist level.  So the pipe jogs across 1 joist using a pre-existing notch.  Here's the configuration:

[image: rerun PVC vanity drain]

However, there was a slight back-pitch issue in that middle angled segment that the second inspector visit revealed.  The inspector said that there's plenty of pitch to either side of the middle segment to fix it without raising the pipe above the joist level again.

I have made the adjustment by installing a 2x4 under the second 45 degree joint that can be seen in the above image.  However, making this adjustment also causes the vertical portion of the drain (in the wall) to slightly protrude beyond the stud surface.  It's difficult to see in the picture, and mainly it's the collar, but that's after I have tried to force it back a bit.  Note, I'm holding a nail plate against the stud to highlight how it goes past the stud:

[image: PVC beyond stud]

You can see that overall, the installation of the 2x4, caused the vertical portion to move forward beyond the studs by the twisting of the strap holding it up seen here:

[image: twisted strap]

However, forcing everything into position established pitches that are to code.

So my question is: will this constant stress on the glued joints, from having forced the pipes into correct positions cause the pipes to eventually fail, and thus, should I re-do the whole thing, gluing it into the correct positions in the first place, or can the glue hold up under that angled stress?

Note, its hard to gauge how much the pipes had to be forced and I'm reluctant to guess but I would say that 3/4" would be an absolute upper limit.  It's probably closer to 1/2".  But to be on the safe side, let's say I lifted that corner with the 2x4 by 3/4".

*CLARIFICATION*: When I installed the 2x4 to prop up that one joint, it accomplished its goal in putting that middle segment at the minimum pitch needed to pass inspection. Doing that also lowered the long segment to its minimum pitch (think see-saw where the strap is the fulcrum).  After the 2x4 adjustment, the only place where I have extra pitch to play with is the segment that goes to where it enters the wall.  In fact, I would like to lower that segment to pull the joint at the top back behind the stud surface.  Removing or lowering the 2x4 would defeat its purpose (which is to get the pitch right).  And given the angle at which the glue dried (see my comments) if I remove the strap, that first 45 degree joint from the tub drain would stick up and re-establish the back-pitch. In other words, it needs pushed down on one end and pushed up on the other.  Which brings me back to my original question - is that constant stress going to make the pipe fail or can the glue handle it?

Comment: I know this doesn't specifically address your question, but is it possible to release that strap and move it back into the wall before reattaching it? That would, at least, allow you to apply drywall without a bulge.

Comment: @Freeman - yes, I definitely intend to do that, that is, if the answer to my question is that the stress on the joints is a non-issue, though I just went and held a straight-edge up to the 2 studs and the 90 degree joint does go past the stud face by a millimeter or 2 on one side. There is a slight angle to the right.  So it would have to be forced back another couple millimeters regardless of the strap.

Comment: ...or else I can just cut a bigger hole in the drywall.

Comment: You used a 2x4 in the middle to raise the pipe to achieve the needed pitch. Inspector stated there was more than enough vertical space to achieve the pitch. Just reduce the 2x4 thickness by 1/4". That will lower the section of pipe at the wall sufficient to be below the joist level. – The pitch needs to be minimum 1/8" per foot. Also as others have commented, Loosen and readjust all the straps. Programmer66 1 min ago

Comment: Without the 2 x 4 as-is, the back-pitch will return. The way the middle segment was glued creates a natural back pitch. The reason for this is that when the plumber originally showed me what he had done, he had the pipes above the floor even higher than the original pipe 2 joists over. He had created way more pitch than was necessary which exacerbated the height issue. That's the position that the pipes' glue dried in. And that's why the straps and propping are necessary to force the pipes into a position where are the pitches are correct and the pipes are below the joist level.

Comment: So effectively lowering the 2x4 recreates the pitch problem. In fact, I could lower the 90° joint where it enters the wall. That is where I have extra pitch at the moment, but I have not been able to force that into a better angle and the way it is right now, all I should have to do is notch the plywood in two positions where the joints are and about 6 inches of the end of the pipe where it goes up to the wall. The longest portion of pipe is currently at its minimum pitch. The only place where I currently have extra pitch is that last segment going into the wall

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a comprehensive solution, but here are some general notes that may help. This isn't rocket science, so just fiddle until it's right, then glue it up.

- Yes, stress on fittings is a problem. We've seen the results on this site, where elbows have actually cracked over time.
- You can probably replace that strap with simple plumber's strapping--metal tape with holes punched in it. It's narrower than what's there now.
- All pipes must be free to move without rubbing under tension. If they can't, they'll creak and tick when you drain warm water. My own kitchen sink vent ticks if I pour hot water down the drain.

Comment: Had another plumber come & eval everything. He didn't have a particular problem w/ the stressed joints I was concerned w/, but he said that pretty much "everything" was wrong & he had no confidence that the 1st guy would do the remainder correctly, so he suggested I get an estimate to have them take over. One point relevant to this issue is that the connector on the flange for the drain is higher than the old flange, which is the main reason I have this issue in the 1st place. He didn't like the rubber connection to the pipe that goes to the basement, so I may end up having it redone anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You solved  your original problem in the wrong sequence by placing the blocking board first.
My suggestion to gain the pitch and solve your issue is to:

1. Remove your current support 2x4.
2. Loosen all the support straps
3. Place a blocking/support  board at the high end to just bring the pipe flush with the joist.  This could just be a piece of wood directly under the pipe.  You might be able to use a strap to hold it in this position.  (flush with the top of the joist).
4. Now add your blocking/support pieces, cut to the correct thickness in the middle sections to maintain a consistent pitch (min 1/8” per foot.
   This should minimize the stress on the pipes and gain you the pitch you need.

[image]

> OP-
> So my question is: will this constant stress on the glued joints, from having forced the pipes into correct positions cause the pipes to eventually fail, and thus, should I re-do the whole thing, gluing it into the correct positions in the first place, or can the glue hold up under that angled stress?

I believe that the sequence I outline below which is just reangling the pipes does not have the same level of stress as your original fix.  I raised the far end and aligned the middle section to continue the line.

Additional Notes added based on OP new comments.
If you don't see this solution is not workable.  Then I would look at replacing the long section up through where your plate is on the wall.  This would give you the proper alignment and provide enough length to insert a coupler to do the replacement section.

Comment: I think there are some misunderstandings here still. So strap 1 (top label/arrow in your annotated pic) holds the pipe down from the original glued position (which was over 3/4" above the joists at the wall), If you loosen/release it, the pipe will pop up. At its current position, without the 2x4 I added, creates a slight backpitch in the middle segment where the second strap is. I.e. from the wall, the pitch would go down (seg 1), up (seg 2), then down (seg 3) to the tub drain... (1/2)

Comment: Like, if you cut off the whole pipe and laid it on a flat surface, the segment that goes under the wall would be up off the ground because the plumber glued everything way above the joist level. And the connection with the tub drain is under counter-clockwise rotational stress. So loosening either strap will cause pitch problems. So either it has straps holding it down and a block to hold that joint up, or the whole thing needs redone. (2/2)